# Why should selectors always return immutable when using immutable data structures in redux.?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, immutable.js, reselect

According to the redux FAQ from here https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.md#what-are-some-opinionated-best-practices-for-using-immutable-js-with-redux:

"Your selectors should return Immutable.JS objects". "Always".

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a disclaimer, this isn't "always" the case, but the docs are trying to point you in the right direction for most cases.

Since reselect memoizes the return result of selectors, returning a mutable object leaves you susceptible to tricky bugs. Imagine the following scenario:

```
// Immutable State
{
  todos: [{ text: "hey"}, { todo: "text"}]
}

// Selectors

const getTodos = createSelector(state => state.todos, immutableTodos => immutableTodos.toJS())
```

The `getTodos` selector is returning a plain JS object, which by default is mutable. Now imagine multiple smart components that are using the `getTodos` selector.

```
class EditTodos extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { todos: props.todos }
  }

  addUnsavedTodo(newTodo) {
    // Accidentally mutate the return result of getTodos
    const newTodos = this.state.todos.push(newTodo)
    this.setState({ todos: newTodos })
  }

  render() { // Some components for adding unsaved todos }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ todos: getTodos(state))
```

A second component also using `getTodos` would see the new "unsaved" todo as soon as `addUnsavedTodo` is called, which would most likely be unintentional. All calls to `getTodos`, assuming redux `state` is unchanged, will get the same reference and any mutations will affect all consumers.

The example above is contrived, but hopefully it demonstrates one of the reasons that returning plain JS objects can be risky.

Furthermore, as the docs [mention](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.md#limit-your-use-of-tojs), you should limit your use of `toJS` since it has performance implications. There is no benefit to converting your immutable object into a plain JS object within a selector

Comment: If I dont put `toJS` inside the selector where should I put it? It seems too extra to make an extra container component to call `toJS`, or do you not think so.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use ImmutableJS inside your components as well, so that you never have to call `toJS`. It would help if I had more details about what you're trying to accomplish. Do you have a link to a github gist or a repo?

Comment: Your post and comment has cleared it up for me. Thanks a lot!